# When coding a Wordpress theme, where does the theme (i.e. the presentation) end and the plugin (i.e. the functionality) begin?

Tags: plugins, theme-development

The best guideline I have seen for what should be in a theme is to put "functionality" in a plugin.

I am looking at adding more "premium features" like jQuery image sliders. This requires a back-end user interface for selecting featured content to slide. Is this presentation?

How about shortcodes? A shortcode is a simple hook that enables you to call a PHP function by adding something such as [shortcode] to a post or page. I see this in themes all the time. Is it presentation?

I am unable to sort it out!

Answer (score 4):

I would say that one line would be ***presention* versus *creation* of content**.

It is one thing to have a slider that displays certain posts; it is another entirely to have a *new post type* for the slider. A slider can be set to display content based on existing taxonomies, or existing post meta (such as sticky posts), which would merely be *presentation* of content. Asking the user to upload slider images to a custom post type would be *creation* of content.

A shortcode that gets added to the *post content* is, IMHO, *always* Plugin territory. In terms of *presentation* versus *creation* of content, a post-content shortcode represents *creation* of content. Consider what happens when the Theme is switched: suddenly the parsed shortcode content is replaced with an ugly shortcode.

Another line is **site functionality**. In almost *all* cases, site functionality - which almost always is agnostic toward the presentation of content - is Plugin territory. This would include things like removing the WordPress version meta tag, or adding Google Analytics.